# postgres: join tables, order by GREATEST

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, order-by

Having the following table structure

```
table1
  id: BIGSERIAL
  updated_at: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
  ...

CREATE INDEX table1_updated_at ON table2(updated_at);
```

```
table2
  table1_id: BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
  updated_at: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
  ...

CREATE INDEX table2_updated_at ON table1(updated_at);
```

trying to get results ordered by the most recently updated like:

```sql
select * from table 1 a
inner join table2 b on a.id = b.table1_id
order by GREATEST(a.updated_at, b.updated_at)
limit 100
```

But running into performance issues on large tables. I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem. The pattern seems common enough to me.

It looks like postgres isn't able to combine the indices for `updated_at` when using `GREATEST`. Which seems kind of odd to me because if I have two large ordered lists, and want to get the 100 greatest values across the two lists, I don't have to traverse them completely, right?

**edit**

As requested, here's a [`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`](https://explain.depesz.com/s/rYUt)

Comment: there you go: https://explain.depesz.com/s/rYUt

Comment: The sort isn't your problem. It's the join and the seq scans that are responsible for 94% of the runtime.

Comment: That's odd, removing the `order by` part of the query finishes under one second: https://explain.depesz.com/s/cmAD

Comment: Try a different ORDER BY clause, since a LIMIT without an ORDER BY gives the engine complete freedom to retrieve ANY 100 rows, negating the need to perform the full join.

Comment: with the order by, Postgres is forced to go through all rows in both tables and thus it needs to scan both tables and process the join for all rows.

Comment: Why is it forced to go through all rows? both indices are ordered, so it shouldn't have to traverse them completely to combine them with `GREATEST`, right?

Comment: Because the join needs to be done before it can sort the rows. And the available indexes won't allow to combine sorting and joining. Try an index on `table1 (id, updated_at);` and `table2 (table1_id, updated_at)`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work neither

Comment: Are the `updated_at` values somehow in the same range? Maybe you could just pick the 500 oldest rows from table1 and then join that (partial) result to table2 and then order that result by the result of the `coalesce()`. That **is** a different query result, but maybe that that would suffice?

Comment: No, they can be anything. For now I've used a query that approximates the desired result enough in my problem domain, so the practical part of this question is solved. But I'm still interested in a proper answer to this use case. I'm a bit surprised I can't find anything about it, it seems like a common enough query to want to do that it should be optimizable.